# Represent hex form of integer > 31 in the form '\x020'

Tags: python, character-encoding, hex

I'm trying to write a Python function that does RLE encoding of a UTF-8 string to bytes. Given `"abbcccddddaaaaaa"` it will return `b'\x01a\x02b\x03c\x04d\x06a'`.

I've almost solved it, except that I'm stuck with converting my run length (integer) into hex *in the desired format*, which is character-like (`\x`), not number-like (`0x`).

I need a function that will take in a decimal number and return it in hex in the form `'\x<hex form>'`. For example, this is the behaviour of `chr()` for numbers up to 31:

```
chr(1)
> '\x01'
chr(31)
> '\x1f'
```

However above 31 it prints the character.

Things which don't work:

```
hex(32)
> '0x20'

re.sub('0', '\', hex(32), count=1)
> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

re.sub('0', '\\', hex(32), count=1)
> error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 0

re.sub('0', r'\\', hex(32), count=1)
> '\\x20'
```

Desired outcome:

```
my_func(32)
> '\x20'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format string:

```
>>> def my_func(n):
...  return f'\\x{n:02x}'
...
>>> print(my_func(32))
\x20
>>> print(''.join([my_func(n) for n in s]))
\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff
```

If you want to override the *display* of a byte string, you could use:

```
>>> class Bytes(bytes):
...  def __repr__(self):
...   return "b'" + ''.join([f'\\x{n:02x}' for n in self]) + "'"
...
>>> s = b'abc'
>>> s
b'abc'
>>> Bytes(s)
b'\x61\x62\x63'
```

Or just use a function:

```
>>> def display(s):
...   print("b'" + ''.join([f'\\x{n:02x}' for n in s]) + "'")
...
>>> display(s)
b'\x61\x62\x63'
```

Comment: This works for printing, but I guess what I want is to "fool" Python into thinking it's a character, so that it natively uses the `\x` prefix over `0x`, so it's stored internally as `\x` and not `\\x`. Is that possible?

Comment: There's no "stored internal as \xnn".  A byte is a byte.  The **default** display of a byte string is escape codes for non-ASCII and non-printable bytes, and the actual ASCII character for printable ASCII bytes.  You want to generate your own custom display of the byte string.

Comment: Ok, I see. Still, I'm not sure how to express the problem but I've added context to the question. Essentially I need to convert `"abbcccddddaaaaaa"` to `b'\x01a\x02b\x03c\x04d\x06a'` (not `b'\\x01a\\x02b\\x03c\\x04d\\x06a'`).

Comment: Again, that's just a difference in *display*.   `b'abc' == b'\x61\x62\x63'`.  Internally, it is just three bytes in memory.

Comment: @Josh I updated my answer with a way to override the display of a bytes object.

Comment: +1 because I appreciate your answer but it still isn't what I need. I think I was on the wrong track and misled you, by focusing on the print statement. I need to convert int 255 to `ÿ`, ie ASCII char 255, but represent it in bytes as `b'\xff'` (255) and not `bytes('ÿ', 'utf-8')`, which is `b'\xc3\xbf'`.

Comment: That's a matter of encoding.  `bytes('ÿ', 'latin1')` will output `b'\xff'`, but  `bytes('a','latin1')` will still print `b'a'`.  `latin1` encoding maps Unicode U+0000 to U+00FF (the Latin 1 symbols) to bytes 0x00-0xff.

Comment: You can also just do `bytes([n])` to get a byte of a specific value.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!!